REST API with large payload
We have a business partner who is insisting on sending large payload of sizes over 100MB on our REST API call. They will call this API of ours every 5 minutes. Although we are trying to explain to them the right way to do this, they don't seem to budge. My application is on AWS and following options were considered:

API Gateway: Ruled out because of its 10MB payload restriction
API Gateway generating pre-signed URL to S3: Ruled out as they don't want to call our API twice; first to get the pre-signed URL and then to actually post the payload.
Apigee Edge bases request streaming: Apigee doesn't recommend this beyond payload size of 10MB.

What else are our options here?

What's the issue with running a HTTP server and streaming the request? There's nothing inherently bad with larger payloads. If the end-goal is getting this file on S3 most server-side HTTP frameworks support handling streams out of the box.

"we are trying to explain to them the right way to do this" What is the right way to do this? Absent other specific requirements or constraints where a 100MB payload isn't feasible for some reason, I don't see why this is not a "right way".

@Evert The requirement is to process the contents with complex logic in near-real time. Our Org has set some standards for API gateway like Apigee Edge or AWS API gateway. If I come up with an exclusive HTTP server I will have to provide and maintain the cross cutting authentication, authorization, etc. separately.

@esqew The "right way" I was referring to was to get the Client to call a API that will provide them with a pre-signed URL where they can upload the JSON file. However, as of now they seem reluctant to adopt this and are expecting us to provide a single API.

If your stack can't handle basic HTTP functions, what kind of answer are you looking for here? Use literally any technology that lets you handle streams.
